# AWS KMS CLI Command

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-kms

I am trying to construct a command, which will list kms keys from my aws account, but there is a problem

every kms keys is having tags, like "env prod" i want to list all kms keys which match certain tags

```
% aws kms list-resource-tags --key-id 01e685-a1-482-ba3-9c4ac3adf 
{
    "Tags": [
        {
            "TagKey": "env",
            "TagValue": "prod"
        },
        {
            "TagKey": "owner",
            "TagValue": "kms"
        },
    ]
}
```

```
% aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --region us-east-1 --resource-type-filters kms --tag-filters Key=Initiator,Values=Terraform
{
    "ResourceTagMappingList": [
        {
            "ResourceARN": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "env",
                    "Value": "prod"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "hello",
                    "Value": "hello"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Initiator",
                    "Value": "Terraform"
                },
                {
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS `kms` does not support it. But you can use `resourcegroupstaggingapi`

```bash
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --region us-east-2 \
  --resource-type-filters kms --tag-filters Key=env,Values=prod
```

Update select key ids.

```
--query 'ResourceTagMappingList[].ResourceARN' | jq '.[]' -r | awk -F'/' '{print $2}'
```

Comment: i tried command provided by you and output contains resourcearn with tags, i updated output in question sections

Comment: I add extra part to get only key ids with tags provided

Answer (score 0):

aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --region us-west-2 --resource-type-filters kms |jq -r '.ResourceTagMappingList[]|{kms_arn:.ResourceARN, tags: .Tags[]|select(.Key=="Environment") |select( .Value |contains("temp"))}' |jq -r '.kms_arn' |cut -d '/' -f 2